# Convert this from Python into Java

Tags: java, android, python

How can I convert this into Java(Android) code?

```
a = input()
asplit = a.split()
mapy = map(int, asplit)
suma = sum(mapy)
```

I've tried this:

```
EditText marks;
String value= marks.getText().toString();
String[] myList = value.split(" ");
int marksfinal=Integer.parseInt();
```

but it doesn't work
I want to convert the user input which will be digits, into an array of digits, them calculate the sum of the array.

Comment: Summary of Python code: take user input, split it on whitespace (arbitrary width), convert the resulting list of strings into integers and sum those integers. Input `42  38 -50`, result is 30.

Comment: You just need a loop to sum all the values in the array. `int marksfinal=0; for(String s : myList) marksFinal += Integer.parseInt(s);`

Comment: @ZouZou make that an answer, no?

Comment: +1 to the Q for not being "Please do this for me even though I haven't tried"

Answer (score 3):

You just need a loop to sum all the values in the array.

```
int marksfinal=0; 
for(String s : myList) 
   marksfinal += Integer.parseInt(s);
```

Also if you want to split on arbitratry width for whitespaces use :

```
String[] myList = value.split("\\s+");
```